# Meteor not updating record when observing for changes

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework

I have this piece of code where I listen for newly added items to a collection. When an item is received I want to update it immediately and mark it as `received`. The initial status is `queued`.

```
    var invites = Invites.find( {} );

    //  Watch for new invites
    invites.observeChanges( {
        added  : function ( id, invite ) {
            Invites.update( invite._id, {
                $set: {
                    status: 'received'
                }
            }, function ( error, affected_rows ) {
                console.log( error, affected_rows );// prints undefined
            } );
        }
    } );
```

The problem is that the status never changes. If I refresh the page the status will switch to `received` so it somehow remains stuck in the process.

I even tried doing the update server side by calling a remote method without any luck.

Btw, this is a mobile app using meteor, angular, ionic.

Comment: are you sure added is called? add a console log before updating invites. also print id and invite

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I already printed everything possible. Even the update callback returns. If the id was invalid, the object wouldn't get updated when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer my own. You need to call setTimeout before sending method calls or updates from with the observe block. See this issue for a discussion:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/907